# Using Hudson and Maven to release an application for multiple platforms

Tags: java, hudson, maven

This question is not really about best practices or architecture, but about how to specifically configure Hudson and Maven to accomplish what I want. I'm a bit lost.

I have a Java application which uses SWT, and I need to build copies for different platforms. For now, all I need is Linux i386 and Linux amd64, but in the future, I need to add Windows x86/x64 as well, so I want to make sure I set it up "right" the first time around.

My application has all of the dependencies and other information listed in the Project pom.xml, including the different SWT jars to grab depending on OS, arch, and family.

My question is, how do I do builds for both linux i386 and linux amd64 with a minimal amount of configuration duplication? Right now I'm doing the following:

- Project specifies all dependencies in pom.xml, and this project is set to build in Hudson and deploy the resulting .jar to Nexus
- Builder-linux-i386 runs after Project and specifies any JNI files for i386 and uses the de.tarent maven-pkg-plugin to grab the project jar from Nexus and assemble it along with all dependencies into a single 'fat' jar file, and then into a .deb file for installation.
- Builder-linux-amd64 does the same, but for amd64 files

I have been trying to specify which dependencies to use in the Builder projects by adding `-P profilename` to their Hudson projects, where `profilename` is a profile named in the Project pom. Maven doesn't seem to like this and prints that it is not activating that profile. It only uses the default profile from Project's pom.

What is the correct way to set this up? I want to have all of my dependencies specified in my Project pom, and have a Hudson project which compiles the jar for that project and deploy it to Nexus, and then **independent** projects which grab that jar and assemble it along with platform-specific files for release. I don't want to build the entire original project repeatedly, and I don't want to have a ton of duplicated configuration info or copy-pasted poms.

I have it working for unix-amd64 only because that's what the build machine is, so Maven targets that architecture. Also, I feel like the setup isn't as clean as it could be. Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builder projects do not see the profiles from the main Project because it is not actually a parent. I cannot define it as a  in the builder projects because my projects are not set up that way, and I'm building using variables like ${SVN_REVISION}, which maven does not like.

I have given up and instead copy-pasted the profiles into the 'builder' projects. This isn't the prettiest but for now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have an syntax error. It needs to be `-Pprofilename`. It works for me this way.

**Edit**

Since the profile is read. There might be an syntax error in your profile configuration. I found a profile in one of projects, that I integrate into our CI environment. It defines some dependencies, it might help you.

```
    <profile>
        <id>junit</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. Maven notices the -P flag just fine, and prints that it is not activating the profile.

Comment: Whats the reason for not activating it?

Comment: Try to run the build again with `-e -X` This will produce way more output.

Answer (score 0):

*Profiles should work in the way you desciped it (you could post an other question about this).*

But at (least for web applications) there is an other way: Try to use classifier instead of profiles to build for different environments. -- You can have a look at this blog: http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/21/one-artifact-with-multiple-configurations-in-maven/

The purpuse of this solution is, that you are able to build (if you want (controlled by an profile)) for all environments at once.